# cant toggle slide the div left

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble sliding a div from the left side, I have done this before and it worked fine but i'm not sure this time for some reason it doesnt really slide at all.
it seems to slide a couple milimeters then appears to .show the rest of the div.

I have tried

```
$('#menu_area').toggle('slide', { direction: 'left' }, 1000);
```

and

```
var left = $('#menu_area').offset().left;
$("#menu_area").css({left:left}).animate({"left":"140px"}, 500, function(){
```

this is my link

http://2click4.com/new/place2.php?id=CoQBcQAAAGqvOgbp0tJu7kVVn9hxur12lk85dSxYZiWj_2w8aL8yzahacGeo1h9ZZ0cAn2enEK7LirrOR8KBCzDhEdmpRbzlJt8000Ufvbct6lP4VUYQkSDXHq6YdFH_w799dw4HUcIz8pimNOdnIRS3hF8DoAt6RfZn7zC-cLgVvnSH7KdrEhDN4vYCBQkmmat2HkYPJ1S6GhRxB-UeiOXywY_f5qRgL19SVKUCag

Answer (score 1):

**DEMO** http://jsfiddle.net/BywL4/
try to animate width if oyu want sliding effet as show in above link

```
 $(document).on('click','button',function(){
   if($("#expand").css('width') == '0px') {
    $("#expand").animate({"width":"500px"}, "slow"); 
   } else {
    $("#expand").animate({"width":"0px"}, "slow");        
   }
});
```